# Error when verifying ECDSA signature in Java with BouncyCastle

Tags: java, bouncycastle, signature, ecdsa

I have tested a solution to verify an ECDSA signature ([How can I get a PublicKey object from EC public key bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26159149/how-can-i-get-a-publickey-object-from-ec-public-key-bytes/26159150#26159150)) that works perfect with the given data.

This is the data:

```
byte[] pubKey = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary("049a55ad1e210cd113457ccd3465b930c9e7ade5e760ef64b63142dad43a308ed08e2d85632e8ff0322d3c7fda14409eafdc4c5b8ee0882fe885c92e3789c36a7a");
byte[] message = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary("54686973206973206a75737420736f6d6520706f696e746c6573732064756d6d7920737472696e672e205468616e6b7320616e7977617920666f722074616b696e67207468652074696d6520746f206465636f6465206974203b2d29");
byte[] signature = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary("304402205fef461a4714a18a5ca6dce6d5ab8604f09f3899313a28ab430eb9860f8be9d602203c8d36446be85383af3f2e8630f40c4172543322b5e8973e03fff2309755e654");
```

And this is the code (which prints *true*):

```
private static boolean isValidSignature(byte[] pubKey, byte[] message,byte[] signature) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeyException, SignatureException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    Signature ecdsaVerify = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA", new BouncyCastleProvider());
    ecdsaVerify.initVerify(getPublicKeyFromBytes(pubKey));
    ecdsaVerify.update(message);
    return ecdsaVerify.verify(signature);
}

private static PublicKey getPublicKeyFromBytes(byte[] pubKey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    ECNamedCurveParameterSpec spec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("prime256v1");
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDSA", new BouncyCastleProvider());
    ECNamedCurveSpec params = new ECNamedCurveSpec("prime256v1", spec.getCurve(), spec.getG(), spec.getN());
    ECPoint point =  ECPointUtil.decodePoint(params.getCurve(), pubKey);
    ECPublicKeySpec pubKeySpec = new ECPublicKeySpec(point, params);
    ECPublicKey pk = (ECPublicKey) kf.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);
    return pk;
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isValidSignature(pubKey, message, signature));
}
```

**My problem comes when I change the signature and data to an example input from an already implemented system:**

```
final static byte[] pubKey = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary("0447303876C6FED5550DF3EE1136989FCD87293D54A5D8E2F2F6D7FBE9A81089B889A5917443AF33E696178CEF4C9D6A4288B2745B29AF6C8BCAD1348F78EB9F9B");
final static byte[] message = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary("02158001f53611a06e2d1a270000013ed9305dc2780524015110500000002d0100140092569202017aa00c5dd30000000000000000000000000000000007d1000001020001b20788b80059f48d95cdefc8c6000200200030d41e0000012016840310a50733a9870fffd0430100");
final static byte[] signature = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary("531F8918FF250132959B01F7F56FDFD9E6CA3EC2144E12A6DA37C281489A3D96");
```

New data outputs this error:

```
java.security.SignatureException: error decoding signature bytes.
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.util.DSABase.engineVerify(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineVerify(Signature.java:1178)
    at java.security.Signature.verify(Signature.java:612)
    at its.sec.exec.TestProgram.isValidSignature(TestProgram.java:168)
    at its.sec.exec.TestProgram.execution(TestProgram.java:101)
    at its.sec.exec.TestProgram.main(TestProgram.java:55)
```

I assume the problem is about the signature that comes with the *secured message* because:

- The key pair is the same length and format that the example. And are correct since it comes from the certificate that signs the message.
- The message itself (payload) shouldn't affect the security process.

Last thing worth mention is that my documentation says that the signature must be preceded by a field called "R" which *"contains the x coordinate of the elliptic curve point resulting from multiplying the generator element by the ephemeral private key"* and its length must be the same as the signature (32 byte).

Can someone point me out what I'm missing here?

**EDIT: Solution**

As Peter Dettman pointed in his answer, the `signature` was not correctly formatted (also content was incorrect too) in order to be computed by the `verify()` method. [Here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1795/how-can-i-convert-a-der-ecdsa-signature-to-asn-1) is a good explanation that mainly says that:

> When encoded in DER, this (signature) becomes the following sequence of bytes:
>
> `0x30 b1 0x02 b2 (vr) 0x02 b3 (vs)`
>
> where:
>
> - b1 is a single byte value, equal to the length, in bytes, of the remaining list of bytes (from the first 0x02 to the end of the encoding);
> - b2 is a single byte value, equal to the length, in bytes, of (vr);
> - b3 is a single byte value, equal to the length, in bytes, of (vs);
> - (vr) is the signed big-endian encoding of the value "r", of minimal length;
> - (vs) is the signed big-endian encoding of the value "s", of minimal length.

Applying that change, `signature` grows to 70 bytes and the execution outputs no error.

Comment: Beware the difference between an ASN.1 DER encoded integer and a unsigned integer of the same size as the key - easy to make mistakes with regards to left padding with zero valued bytes!

Comment: Great! it works. Don't forget to add a 0x00 ad the beginning of both vr and vs if they have the MSb set to 1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The expected ECDSA signature format that the BC (and other provider) implementations work with is a DER-encoded ASN.1 sequence containing two integer values `r` and `s`. This signature format has been specified in ANSI X9.62. This is the format in the first set of data you give (note that `signature` is a total of at least 70 bytes).

In the second set of data, `signature` is only 32 bytes, and is not an ASN.1 sequence at all. I would guess that this value is only the `s` value, and it is missing the `r` value and the ASN.1 INTEGER encoding for them both, instead encoding the values as a unsigned big integer value with the same size as the key.

Comment: To convert from one format to the other in Java. https://gist.github.com/DinoChiesa/7520e1dea6e79888acab8ea8206afe92

Answer (score 4):

this is a sample code to write r and s in ASN1 DER encoded format

```
    // construct the ASN1Sequence with r and s
    ByteArrayOutputStream outs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    byte radd = (byte)(((signed[0] & 0x80) > 0) ? 1 : 0);
    byte sadd = (byte)(((signed[32] & 0x80) > 0) ? 1 : 0);

    byte length = (byte)(0x44 + radd + sadd);

    outs.write(0x30);
    outs.write(length); // length 68 bytes +
    outs.write(0x02); // ASN1Integer
    outs.write(0x20 + radd); // length 32 bytes
    if(radd > 0)
        outs.write(0x00); // positive val
    outs.write(signed, 0, 32);
    outs.write(0x02); // ASN1Integer
    outs.write(0x20 + sadd); // length 32 bytes
    if(sadd > 0)
        outs.write(0x00); // positive val
    outs.write(signed, 32, 32);

    signed = outs.toByteArray();
```